# push object to array containing array in recursive function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to parse exif data (object) to an array for a Meteor web app while retaining some of the tree information, i.e:

```
{exif:{size:{width:123}}}
```

would become

```
[{key:width, value:123, path:["exif","size"]}]
```

This works fine except that `objArray.path` is always empty, regardless of the value in `p`. On a whim I added `depth: p.length`, and this value gets added correctly.

So if `p = ["Channel statistics", "Red"]`, then I would expect `objArray.path = ["Channel statistics", "Red"]` and `depth = 2` but `objArray.path` always returns `[]`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
parseObject = function (obj) {
po = function (obj, p, objArray) {
  _.each(obj, function (v, k) {
    if (typeof v==='object') {
      objArray.push({ key: k, value: null, path: p, depth: p.length});
      p.push(k);
      return po(obj[k], p, objArray);
    }
    objArray.push({ key: k, value: v, path: p, depth: p.length });
  });
  p.pop();
  return objArray;
};
return po(obj, [], []);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you add `p` to an object in `objArray`, you are adding a reference to an array that `p` is a reference to it too. Therefore, everytime you change `p`, you basically change `p` in all the other objects you put as well. Since you always do a `p.pop();` action in the end, `p` is empty in all the objects that were pushed into objArray when the algorithm finishes.

The solution to this would be to insert a clone of `p` into the object that gets pushed into objArray.
Since `p` is an array of plain strings, I think _.clone(p) should be enough (it's a shallow copy, so nested arrays or objects would be copied-by-reference).

Example:

```
objArray.push({ key: k, value: v, path: _.clone(p), depth: p.length });
```

if `p` would have nested objects/arrays, you would have to do a deep copy, which is a bit more complex, and can be found on google / stackoverflow.

Comment: awesome! _.clone() does the job. Is this 'phenomena' confined to arrays + recursion?

Comment: the phenomenon occurs whenever you assign an object, that is not of 'primitive' type (like number, boolean, string) to a variable. object are referred to by their address in memory, and not by their value.
so say you have

    var a = {key: 'value'};
    var b = a;

`a` and `b` point to the same object, so any change you do to `a` will also be visible through `b`, since they point to the same object